# Retrieve every ten years

Tags: python

I attempt to retrieve a decades list with least codes:

```
def get_decade_list(start, end):
    nl = []
    while start < end:
        l = list(range(start, start+10))
        start += 10
        nl.append(l)
    return nl
print get_decade_list(2001, 2201)
```

output:

```
[[2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010],
 [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
...
  [2191, 2192, 2193, 2194, 2195, 2196, 2197, 2198, 2199, 2200],]
```

How to accomplish such a task in a pythonic way?

Comment: python2 or python3?

Comment: `print` without parentheses implies Python 2 but really, I would actually post a solution in Python 3 just to nudge the OP to realize that's what they need to move to.

Comment: What about `range(2001,2201,10)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.7 I would do

```
[range(i, i + 10) for i in range(2001, 2201, 10)]
```

As a generator in Python 2.7

```
(range(i, i + 10) for i in xrange(2001, 2201, 10))
```

Comment: I think there overhead in your code: `range` (in py27) already returns a `list` of elements.

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure of the requirement, but it looks like you want to return a value every 10 years, for a given range. You can do this in one line, like so:

`range(2001, 2211, 10)`

This outputs:

`[2001, 2011, 2021, 2031, 2041, 2051, 2061, 2071, 2081, 2091, 2101, 2111, 2121, 2131, 2141, 2151, 2161, 2171, 2181, 2191, 2201]`

Comment: looks more like a list of lists, where the innermost list contains all the years that form the decade. i.e. 2001..2010, 2011..2020

Answer (score 2):

That would be

```
[[x for x in range(i, i + 10)] for i in range(2001, 2201, 10)]
```

which returns a list of lists under both Python 2 and 3.

```
[[2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010],
 [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
 [2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030],
 [2031, 2032, 2033, 2034, 2035, 2036, 2037, 2038, 2039, 2040],
  ... (omitted)
 [2191, 2192, 2193, 2194, 2195, 2196, 2197, 2198, 2199, 2200]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some python tricks :

- `iter` : create a iterator
- `]*10` : multiply elements in a list
- `izip` : from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)
- `izip(*args)`  : it's the the unzip function
- `map`  :  convert each element

and all together :

```
from itertools import izip

def get_decade_list(start, end):
    args = [iter(xrange(start, end))] * 10
    return list(map(list, izip(*args)))

print get_decade_list(2001, 2201)
```

result is :

```
[[2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010], 
 ...
 [2191, 2192, 2193, 2194, 2195, 2196, 2197, 2198, 2199, 2200]]
```

There is a few difference if `end` is not XX01, this version get only full decades.